# What does if x == ( 1 or 2 ): mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What does this mean in Python:

```
if x == (1 or 2):
```

I know it's different to:

1. `if x == 1 or x == 2:`
2. `if x in (1,2):`

Comment: If means `if x == 1:`. It's either an error or obfuscation.

Comment: I found this issue when I trying practice something. I just can't find out what its mean.

Comment: I've told you exactly what it means. `(1 or 2)` evaluates to `1`, try it out for yourself.

Comment: it's almost a good question, compared to the trash we had tonight...